# Is it possible to solve VRP using OR-Tools CpModel, instead of RoutingModel?

Tags: scheduling, or-tools, vehicle-routing

Is it possible to solve VRP using OR-Tools CpModel, instead of RoutingModel? I want to do synchronized VRP, which is combining vehicle routing and scheduling constraints

Comment: Yes it's possible to use CpModel to model VRPs with specific additional constraints. This discussion in OR-Tools repo could serve as a guide if you're gathering ideas about modeling synchronized VRP: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1047

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes. Is it worthwhile ? it depends.

If you just want to have two persons visit the same virtual place (2 duplicated nodes) at the same time, you can force the time cumul var to be equal when using the routing library.

This will probably more efficient than the CP-SAT VRP code as the routing library is highly tuned.

If you want more complex constraints, you can try CP-SAT.
You can look at ortools/constraint_solver/routing_sat.cc to get some ideas.